# How to truncate a collection in Mongoose

Tags: mongoose

After running my test cases, I want to truncate a collection. I can't find the API in Mongoose -https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/model.html

In other questions, people have mentioned using `drop` and `remove` but I can't find them in the document.